# CompositeDisposable.clear causes OkHttp to throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unbalanced enter/exit

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, okhttp

So I have a simple http request using OkHttp. I do this with RxJava on Android. I add this RxJava call to a `CompositeDisposable` that I then clear on `onStop`. For some reason that is triggering this exception below. I'm a little unsure about how to fix it.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unbalanced enter/exit
       at okio.AsyncTimeout.enter(AsyncTimeout.java:73)
       at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:235)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47)
       at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$AbstractSource.read(Http1Codec.java:363)
       at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1Codec.java:407)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1.read(CacheInterceptor.java:174)
       at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipAll(Util.java:175)
       at okhttp3.internal.Util.discard(Util.java:157)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1.close(CacheInterceptor.java:202)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:469)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.close(RealBufferedSource.java:453)
       at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(Channels.java:255)
       at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel$1.interrupt(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:166)
       at java.lang.Thread.interrupt(Thread.java:957)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:146)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.cancel(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:258)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.dispose(ScheduledRunnable.java:107)
       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:217)
       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:80)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.IoScheduler$EventLoopWorker.dispose(IoScheduler.java:210)
       at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.dispose(Scheduler.java:464)
       at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.dispose(DisposableHelper.java:125)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.dispose(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:74)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.dispose(ObservableObserveOn.java:146)
       at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.dispose(DisposableHelper.java:125)
       at io.reactivex.observers.DisposableObserver.dispose(DisposableObserver.java:91)
       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:217)
       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.clear(CompositeDisposable.java:183)
       at MyActivity.onStop(MyActivity.java:320)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1297)
       at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:7159)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4625)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4691)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap7(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6732)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

The code is basically this:

```
Observable<Stuff> observable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Stuff>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Stuff> e) throws Exception {

           //do OkHttp stuff, call onNext(stuff). 

            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        DisposableObserver<Stuff> disposableObserver = observable
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Stuff>() {......});

        disposables.add(disposableObserver);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a bug in some Android VMs that interacts poorly with the new D8 compiler.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3641#issuecomment-370717021

Google has recently improved D8 to avoid triggering the bug.

Comment: Oh wow, did not expect that. So I have to wait for Android Studio 3.2?

Comment: I'm still seeing this with the latest D8 on AS 3.1.3, should it be fixed already there?