# NetworkOnMainThreadException while RxJava CompositeDisposable gets disposed

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, okhttp

Have another strange issue with RxJava, and I'm guessing it is related to [CompositeDisposable.clear causes OkHttp to throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unbalanced enter/exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581241/compositedisposable-clear-causes-okhttp-to-throw-java-lang-illegalstateexception)

Is it the same issue?

The code looks like this:

```
Observable<Stuff> observable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Stuff>() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Stuff> e) throws Exception {

               //do OkHttp stuff, only place with network calls, then call onNext(stuff). 

                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            DisposableObserver<Stuff> disposableObserver = observable
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Stuff>() {......});

            disposables.add(disposableObserver);
```

The exception looks like this:

```
Caused by android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
       at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:120)
       at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
       at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47)
       at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$AbstractSource.read(Http1Codec.java:363)
       at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1Codec.java:407)
       at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipAll(Util.java:175)
       at okhttp3.internal.Util.discard(Util.java:157)
       at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSource.close(Http1Codec.java:424)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:469)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1.close(CacheInterceptor.java:206)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:469)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.close(RealBufferedSource.java:453)
       at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(Channels.java:255)
       at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel$1.interrupt(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:166)
       at java.lang.Thread.interrupt(Thread.java:957)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:146)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.cancel(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:258)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.dispose(ScheduledRunnable.java:107)
       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:217)
       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:80)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.IoScheduler$EventLoopWorker.dispose(IoScheduler.java:210)
       at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.dispose(Scheduler.java:464)
       at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.dispose(DisposableHelper.java:125)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.dispose(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:74)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.dispose(ObservableObserveOn.java:146)
       at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.dispose(DisposableHelper.java:125)
       at io.reactivex.observers.DisposableObserver.dispose(DisposableObserver.java:91)
       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:217)
       at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.clear(CompositeDisposable.java:183)
       at mypackage.MyActivity.onStop(MyActivity.java:320)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1297)
       at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:7168)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4543)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4609)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap7(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Edit: This is essentially the `OkHttp` code inside the `subscribe` method:

```
try {
            OkHttpClient.Builder okClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            OkHttpClient client = okClientBuilder.build();
            Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder()
                    .get()
                    .url(address);
            Call okCall = client.newCall(builder.build());
            Response res = okCall.execute();
            InputStream stream = res.body().byteStream();
            Parser parsed = Parser.parse(stream);
            stream.close();
            e.onNext(parsed);
     } catch (IOException ex) {
        e.onError(ex);
     }
```

Comment: Can you fill in what your `DisposableObserver` is doing as well? My theory on what's happening is your observer is attempting to do something when the observable is disposed.

Comment: I'm not overriding `dispose()` on `DisposableObserver` as it is final.

Comment: You've still replaced the contents of your created DisposableObserver, making it very difficult to narrow down what the issue is.

Comment: None of my `onNext`, `onError`, and `onComplete` are called according to the stacktrace, unless I'm misreading it. Seems like it calls `dispose` on the `CompositeDisposable` which in turn does a bunch of stuff, which involves calling `FutureTask.cancel`, and that triggers the `java.lang.Thread.interrupt`. It is because of that that I think it might be related to another issue I've had with this exact same code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581241/compositedisposable-clear-causes-okhttp-to-throw-java-lang-illegalstateexception

Comment: Please provide impl of " //do OkHttp stuff" and "subscribeWith". Possibly https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1125

Comment: I've added the code at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code that actually triggers the issue, but reading through your stack trace shows that

- `MyActivity.onStop()` is called, then
- `CompositeDisposable.clear()` is called, then
- `Thread.interrupt()` is called, then
- the network code tries to shut down its operation

Since all of these are done on the main thread, the exception is thrown.

You need to isolate your networking code, which only has a commented placeholder in your question, so that starting and stopping the network accesses is done in an IO thread and not the main thread. You may have to use a different observable creator method.

Comment: The only place with networking code is `public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Stuff> e) throws Exception {
              
                   //do OkHttp stuff, only place with network calls, then call onNext(stuff). 
              
                    }`

Comment: The `create()` operator may not be the appropriate one for handling cancelling the subscription.