# Unbalanced enter/exit on OkHttp

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, okhttp

So I have an exception every so often that says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unbalanced enter/exit` and this happens when the `onStop` of my activity calls `disposables.clear()`.

I [asked about it before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581241/compositedisposable-clear-causes-okhttp-to-throw-java-lang-illegalstateexception) and was told it was a D8 bug but I'm on the latest D8 now, or whatever the latest is for Android Studio 3.1.3 and it is still happening.

I also [asked about it on github for OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4110) and was told to find a way to call `call.cancel()`.

So my question is, how can I make `disposables.clear()` call `call.cancel()`?

This is the exception:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unbalanced enter/exit
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.enter(AsyncTimeout.java:73)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:235)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$AbstractSource.read(Http1Codec.java:363)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:453)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1.read(CacheInterceptor.java:174)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipAll(Util.java:175)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.discard(Util.java:157)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor$1.close(CacheInterceptor.java:202)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:469)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.close(RealBufferedSource.java:453)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:472)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(Channels.java:255)
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel$1.interrupt(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:166)
    at java.lang.Thread.interrupt(Thread.java:956)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.cancel(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:258)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.dispose(ScheduledRunnable.java:107)
    at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:217)
    at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:80)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.IoScheduler$EventLoopWorker.dispose(IoScheduler.java:210)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.dispose(Scheduler.java:464)
    at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.dispose(DisposableHelper.java:125)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.dispose(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:74)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.dispose(ObservableObserveOn.java:146)
    at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableHelper.dispose(DisposableHelper.java:125)
    at io.reactivex.observers.DisposableObserver.dispose(DisposableObserver.java:91)
    at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.dispose(CompositeDisposable.java:217)
    at io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable.clear(CompositeDisposable.java:183)
    at MyActivity.onStop(MyActivity.java:321)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1289)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6841)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3947)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4005)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap25(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1561)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

The code is basically this:

```
Observable<Stuff> observable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Stuff>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Stuff> e) throws Exception {

           //do OkHttp stuff, call onNext(stuff). 

            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        DisposableObserver<Stuff> disposableObserver = observable
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Stuff>() {......});

        disposables.add(disposableObserver);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
e.setCancellable(new Cancellable() {
    @Override
    public void cancel() throws Exception {
        call.cancel();
    }
});
```

Call `setCancellable` of the Emitter inside the `subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Stuff> e)` method, this `Cancellable` will be executed when `Observable` is disposed.

I'm curious about how do you get the `close` method called, in my case, interrupting the thread will never call the `close` method of the `Source`, I have to call `call.cancel()` manually to interrupt the blocking reading.